# Unity Version 1.3 models inside out

Tags: kudan

After updating to Unity version 1.3 I am finding that my models are inside out (i.e. the inside of every element is showing and the depth is back-to-front)

If I turn off 'Apply projection' things look ok again (while, as I remember, things did not look right before with this turned off)

So what does 'ApplyProjection' do? I cant find any information in the docs that actually says anything more than "'ApplyProjection' applies the projection" which does not tell me alot!

Comment: I do something out of the ordinary which is that I load a scene in the background and then move the scenes content into the driver if that makes any difference to things

Comment: So, does it work if you don't load Async?

Comment: Well I need to load Async so I havent tried- as I say it seems to work if I use the opposite 'Apply Projection' setting that I was using in 1.2 (i.e. off) but what I want to know really is what that setting is for so I can sus out if it *should* be on or off

Comment: What you're looking for is https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-projectionMatrix.html. If "Apply Projection" is on, it gets a custom projection matrix and assigns it to the rendering camera. If it's off, it calls ResetProjectionMatrix instead. If you turn off "Apply Projection", the camera will render based off its field of view. I believe this, along with custom shader code, is what allows the plugin to render objects on top of the camera feed and have the camera feed fill the entire screen on all manner of different devices.

Comment: ok so with regards to Kudan then is this maybe supposed to do something about the fact that the resolution is suck at 640x480 (ipad) and is therefore distorted on 16:9 devices (like most phones) maybe?

Comment: OK turns out that you do still need "Apply Projection" in an actual android build- and the objects are not inside out. So its only in the Unity Editor when you are testing an Android project that  this issue seems to now occur